# Does Hill Cipher key differs if the number of letters to be encrypted changed?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, linear-algebra, encryption

If I want to encrypt a letter set of 26 symbols does the key used in hill cipher differs from encrypting a 35-letters set ?

Comment: Better asked at http://crypto.stackexchange.com/, asked like this it does not contain any programming related...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea doesn't change, only the computation varies slightly. I remember from your last question on the Hill Cipher that you would actually like to implement a CBC mode for it. Instead of calculating mod 26, I would recommend you choose to calculate mod 256 instead - this way you will have an easy mapping back and forth to a byte representation of the key, the IV and the resulting ciphertexts. Additionally, it will allow you to use spaces and other punctuation, you could even use UTF-8 or similar encodings for your messages.

The idea of the key will not change mod 256, but it will be calculated a bit differently. Instead of choosing a n x n matrix that is invertible in Z^n/26 you will have to choose a matrix that is invertible in Z^n/256. Say you choose a 3 x 3 matrix, which is still invertible easily enough, then you can check whether the key (matrix) you chose is invertible by checking for a non-zero determinant modulo 256, as outlined in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_cipher). A byte array representation of your key would then simply be an array of length 9, with the straight-forward mapping from matrix to array: element (1,2) (zero-based indexing assumed) would be the fifth element of the array (1*3 + 2) etc.

You would then split your message into 3-byte blocks (use some form of padding if the last block is not aligned to three bytes) that represent the vectors to be multiplied with the key matrix, resulting again in 3-byte output blocks.

As you can see, using the mod 256 representation is pretty neat, because this way encryption/decryption could be used with an identical interface that would also be used for state-of-the-art block ciphers like AES, i.e. you encrypt a message by applying an encryption/decryption function based on a byte array key to the message divided into appropriately sized chunks/blocks.

#### Generating a 3x3 encryption and a decryption matrix in Z^n/256

Generating an encryption matrix simply requires creating a random 3x3 matrix with elements from Z256 until one is found that has a non-zero determinant (mod 256) and a modular inverse element mod 256 (which we will compute using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm). Then, calculating the inverse matrix follows the same rules as calculating a regular 3x3 matrix inverse, except for the fact that all computations need to take place in Z256. There's a closed formula for calculating 3x3 matrix inverses, as found [here](http://www.dr-lex.be/random/matrix_inv.html). We may calculate exactly the same thing using modular arithmetic in Z256 to get an inverse in Z^n/256.

Here's some Ruby code that generates a key matrix and its inverse:

```
require 'matrix'

class Integer
  def modinv(modulus)
    a, b = modulus, self
    q, r = a / b, a % b
    t0, t1 = 0, 1

    while r > 0
      t0, t1 = t1, (t0 - q * t1) % modulus
      a, b = b, r
      q, r = a / b, a % b
    end

    raise RuntimeError.new("#{self} has no inverse modulo #{modulus}") unless b == 1
    t1
  end
end

while true
  m = Matrix.build(3) { rand(0..256) }
  mod_det = m.determinant % 256
  next if mod_det == 0
  begin
    det_inv = mod_det.modinv(256)
    break
  rescue RuntimeError => e
    next
  end
end

inv = Matrix[
  [ (m[2,2]*m[1,1] - m[2,1]*m[1,2]), -(m[2,2]*m[0,1] - m[2,1]*m[0,2]),  (m[1,2]*m[0,1] - m[1,1]*m[0,2])],
  [-(m[2,2]*m[1,0] - m[2,0]*m[1,2]),  (m[2,2]*m[0,0] - m[2,0]*m[0,2]), -(m[1,2]*m[0,0] - m[1,0]*m[0,2])],
  [ (m[2,1]*m[1,0] - m[2,0]*m[1,1]), -(m[2,1]*m[0,0] - m[2,0]*m[0,1]),  (m[1,1]*m[0,0] - m[1,0]*m[0,1])]
].map { |e| e * det_inv % 256 }

p m #=> encryption matrix
p inv #=> decryption matrix
identity = (inv * m).map { |e| e % 256 }
p identity #=> living proof that m * inv is the identity matrix
```

Example output:

```
m   = Matrix[[167, 8, 48], [54, 107, 25], [170, 184, 107]]
inv = Matrix[[119, 152, 136], [184, 235, 231], [174, 120, 59]]
```

Comment: In lack of time, I face problem in understanding the steps of calculating a key 3x3 matrix for 256 characters, if you have any ready matrix key for that, i will appreciate it very much

Comment: you are so awesome .. thanks a lot. I will try is on Java, and back to you

Comment: I take from that it worked? :) Had a lot of fun figuring out the matrix inversion thing, too!

Comment: Thanks Thanks, now I am trying to apply CBC , if I have two blocks like this [15,25,98] and [88,78,61] does the xor(in java) result normally like >> [15^88,25^78,98^61] ?? ..

Comment: Yes, exactly, you XOR them byte by byte.

Comment: do I need to convert integer to anything ?

Comment: I'd convert it to bytes, because you will typically operate on bytes, no?

Comment: please check my question here http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/why-cpc-cryptohraghy-only-encrypt-the-first-block-correctly